# error: InitialLoadEntityManagerProxy is not abstract

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2

I am learning **JavaFX** by looking at the official samples. I installed everything (jdk1.7.0_21, netBean3.7, MySQL, javafx-samples-2.2.21) few weeks ago. After I fixed the MySQL user table issue (one column less in build.xml file of DataAppLoader project), I was able run the DataApp project except the web version (DataAppServer project).

This morning I just updated the NetBeans via its Help menu try to get DataAppServer working. Then I got above compile error. I thought it was the version issue because I still use the 1.7.0_21 JDK.

Then I uninstalled everything related and installed the latest, jdk 1.7.0.25, glassfish 4, javafx-sample-2.2.25 and NetBeans 3.7.1.

I am surprised the database miss match is still there (they may be able to check the database version to determine which insert statement should be used.) and I still cannot compile the samples with this error.

```
error: InitialLoadEntityManagerProxy is not abstract and does not override abstract method <T>getEntityGraphs(Class<T>) in EntityManager
public class InitialLoadEntityManagerProxy implements EntityManager {
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>getEntityGraphs(Class<T>)
```

I really hope it is only my issue but not theirs issue. Otherwise the quality of the release will hurt so many users.

I am using windows 7 64-bit. The correct java.exe and javac.exe are used. I am an Eclipse user. NetBeans IDE is new to me.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I didn't change/add anything except that build.xml to be able to initialize the database.

Comment: Is `InitialLoadEntityManagerProxy` your class or theirs?

Comment: it looks like it gives you a hint:  `and does not override abstract method <T>getEntityGraphs(Class<T>) in EntityManager`

Comment: I didn't change/add anything except that build.xml to initialize the database.

Answer (score 1):

Put your mouse over the class name and hit Alt+Enter (to show hints). Then select implement all abstract methods. That worked for me.